# NodeJS xmldoc check if pair (element, value) exists

Tags: node.js, xml, xml-documentation

I'm trying to check if a pair (element, value) exists in XML. I'm using `xmldoc`

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<listings>
    <listing>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>TEST1</name>
        <description>TEST1</description>
    </listing>
    <listing>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>TEST</name>
        <description>TEST</description>
    </listing>
</listings>
```

My code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require("path");
const xmldoc = require('xmldoc');

const xml = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "./myXML"), 'utf8');
const doc = new xmldoc.XmlDocument(xml);
const check = doc.childWithAttribute('id', '2');
console.log(check);
```

It's returning undefined, but I have an element with the id = 2.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Also, after finding the element, is it possible to delete it?

Thanks

Comment: As per [docs](https://github.com/nfarina/xmldoc#childwithattributenamevalue) the `childWithAttribute` function `Searches for the first child with the given attribute value.`. I assume this means it will **not** recursively search through your doc. You will have to create the code to check the deeper levels

Comment: I realize now that you're actually not looking for an attribute but for a whole name... try `childNamed`

Comment: You're going to have to use https://github.com/nfarina/xmldoc#eachchildfunc and search through it's children I think

Comment: Got it. Thank you